# AJAX a form submission with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, shopify

This is my form, and it works fine, but now I want to AJAX it.

```
<%= form_tag variant_path(variant.id), :method => :put, :class => 'update_inv_form' do %>  
  <%= text_field_tag :inventory_quantity, variant.inventory_quantity %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Update'  %>
<% end %>
```

When I add the :remote => true attribute the form successfully submits via AJAX (I can see it happening on the server and I can see the changes when I refresh the page).  I want to update the view properly to show the changes without refreshing the page.  This is my update action: (Note that I am not working with ActiveRecord Models here.)

```
def update
  variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(params[:id])
  variant.inventory_quantity = params[:inventory_quantity]
  variant.save
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

**UPDATE**
Thank you to the answer that helped me figure this out turns out the solution is exactly as he said, however I ran into a small problem.  The view I wanted to update lives in `app/views/home/index.html.erb`  and I was dealing with this: Variants#update.  (Variants controller, update action)

I was putting my update.js.html in the same directory that my view was: `app/views/home` and my server was throwing a 500 error: Missing Template.  Turns out, I had to create an `app/views/variants/` directory and put the update.js.html file in there.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to change your action to respond to the JS format:

```
def update
  @variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(params[:id])
  @variant.inventory_quantity = params[:inventory_quantity]
  @variant.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

You can then create an `update.js.erb` file with JavaScript that will update the page. Let's say you have a `_variant.html.erb` partial, you could append the variant to a div like this (assuming you are using jQuery):

```
$('.variant-list').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "variant", :object => @variant)) %>');
```

**update**

Here's an example of how you would use the `update.js.erb' file (Note: I have not tried this code). Let's say you have the following code in your`index.html.erb`:

```
<ul class="variants">
    <li id="101">Variant 1</li>
    <li id="102">Variant 2</li>
    <li id="103">Variant 3</li>
</ul>
```

Your `updated.js.erb` could look something like this:

```
$('.variants #<%= @variant.id %>').text('<%= @variant.title %>');
```

What this does is find the variant you just updated in the list, and change the variant title to the new one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later and post an update.  I am not using any partial, this form lives on my index.html.erb page.  And am I supposed to be using the instance variables @variant in my update action instead of the local variables, like you have here?

Comment: Yes, because you'll need access to the variable in your update.js.erb file. I've added to my answer to give you a better idea how to update the page on update.

Comment: Thank you!!  I got stuck a little bit with getting the js template tho execute but ended up figuring it out.  I posted an update.  Thanks again.